# Making category list using unique_array

Tags: php, xml, arrays

i have a question regarding PHP and XML . i have a xml product list which consists of 30 items , and i would like to link them by categories for example if i click the Shoe link , the Shoes list will be appeared .
This is my code :

```
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_file("product.xml");        
echo " Here is my Product category : <br/>" ;
echo "<ol>";

$uniquecategory = array();
$i=0;

foreach ($xml->category as $ourcategory){
$uniquecategory[$i]=$ourcategory;
$i++;
}
$newcategory =array_unique($uniquecategory);
```

The coding is fine until this point ..

```
foreach ($newcategory as $anewcategory){
?>
<li><a href="displayproduct.php?category=<?php echo $anewcategory ?>">
<?php echo $anewcategory;
 ?>
</a></li>
<?php
}

echo "</ol>";
?>
```

im not sure where it went wrong .. when i viewed it on browsers , it only displayed " Here is my Product  category "
help me please , thank you .

this is the xml sample data

```
<product>
<category>Watches</category>
<product_id>0010</product_id>
<title>
Burberry Silver Dial Stainless Steel Mens Watch BU9300  </title>
<description>
Stainless steel case with a stainless steel bracelet. Fixed stainless steel bezel. 
Silver check stamped dial with silver-tone hands and index hour markers. Minute markers around the outer rim.
 Dial Type: Analog. Date display at the 3 o'clock position. Automatic movement. Scratch resistant sapphire crystal. 
 Pull / push crown. Skeleton case back. Case diameter: 42 mm. Round case shape. Band width: 22 mm. Deployment clasp.
 Water resistant at 50 meters / 165 feet. Functions: date, hour, minute, second. Casual watch style.
 Burberry Silver Dial Stainless Steel Mens Watch BU9300.
 </description>
<price>$813.93 </price>
<image_path></image_path>
</product>

<product>
<category>Shades</category>
<product_id>0101</product_id>
<title>
PERSOL - PO0714SM (54) </title>
<description>
 </description>
<price>$380.00 </price>
<image_path></image_path>
</product>
```

Comment: give the sample xml data. then only we can find the problem

Comment: `array_unique` isn't intended for array of objects which you have.

Comment: added xml sample data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code, this will work.
You have to wrapp all the product details inside a base tag like  tag.

```
<?php
$xml = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<products>
<product><category>Watches</category>
<product_id>0010</product_id>
<title>
Burberry Silver Dial Stainless Steel Mens Watch BU9300  </title>
<description>
Stainless steel case with a stainless steel bracelet. Fixed stainless steel bezel. 
Silver check stamped dial with silver-tone hands and index hour markers. Minute markers around the outer rim.
 Dial Type: Analog. Date display at the 3 o'clock position. Automatic movement. Scratch resistant sapphire crystal. 
 Pull / push crown. Skeleton case back. Case diameter: 42 mm. Round case shape. Band width: 22 mm. Deployment clasp.
 Water resistant at 50 meters / 165 feet. Functions: date, hour, minute, second. Casual watch style.
 Burberry Silver Dial Stainless Steel Mens Watch BU9300.
 </description>
<price>$813.93 </price>
<image_path></image_path>
</product>

<product>
<category>Shades</category>
<product_id>0101</product_id>
<title>PERSOL - PO0714SM (54) </title>
<description>ewer</description>
<price>234</price>
<image_path>ww</image_path>
</product>

<product>
<category>Shades</category>
<product_id>010d1</product_id>
<title>PERSOL - dPO0714SM (54) </title>
<description>ewer</description>
<price>23f4</price>
<image_path>wdw</image_path>
</product>
</products>";
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml);

echo " Here is my Product category : <br/>" ;
echo "<ol>";

$uniquecategory = array();
$i=0;

foreach ($xml->product as $product){

$uniquecategory[$i]=$product->category;
$i++;
}
$newcategory =array_unique($uniquecategory);

foreach ($newcategory as $anewcategory){
?>
<li><a href="displayproduct.php?category=<?php echo $anewcategory ?>">
<?php echo $anewcategory;
 ?>
</a></li>
<?php
}

echo "</ol>";
```

Answer (score 0):

$ missing in varibale $i.Change this line

```
$uniquecategory[i]=$ourcategory;
```

to

```
$uniquecategory[$i]=$ourcategory;
```